# The amount of guesses it always take for the computer to guess a number your thinking

Tags: java, logic

Okay, so the problem isn't necessarily the actual code because it works, but rather the logic. The problem is how many guesses will it take the computer to get the number your thinking?  Between 1-100 it will always guess your number in 7 tries no matter what it is as long as it's between 1-100. The next question is what about 1-50, I figured out that it will only take 5 tries to always guess your number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThinkofaNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
    System.out.println();
    int input = 0;
    //guess is equal to half the highest number
    int guess = 50;
    //low is equal to the lowest
    int low = 1;
    //high is equal to the highest number
    int high = 101;
    int tries = 1;

    while (input != 2) {
        System.out.println("Is your number " + guess + "?");
        System.out.println("1: No, my number is lower");
        System.out.println("2: Yes, that is my number");
        System.out.println("3: No, my number is higher");
        System.out.println();

        input = in.nextInt();

        if (input == 1) {
            high = guess;
            guess = low + (guess - low) / 2;
            tries++;

        } else if(input == 3) {
            low = guess;
            guess = guess + (high - guess) / 2;
            tries++;
        }

    }


    System.out.println("Your number is " + guess + "!");

    if (tries  == 1) {

        System.out.println("It took 1 try to guess " + guess);

    } else {


        System.out.println("It took " + tries + " guesses to get " + guess);
    }

}
}
```

The problem is the question then goes on to ask how many do you think the maximum number of guesses would be if the number was between 1 and 400?  What if it were between 1 and 800?  Between 1 and 1600? I think it's trying to get me to find a pattern or a algorithm but I don't see it. What do you guys think?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so I'm not sure why you've posted it here on SO.

Comment: It may actually take 6 guesses for 50 choices.

Comment: It seemed like a programming concept, because it directly relates to the code I posted. However, I am new here, would there have been a better place to post this?

Comment: @Jeremy http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you are talking about is a binary search algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: You might want to add the two essential pieces of information: about having O(log(n)) as upper limit for the number of "trials"; and of course - that this works for **sorted** data only.

Answer (score 2):

It is a binary search algorithm as Wojciech said. The number 7 comes from the following log2 (100) = 6.6 round up to 7.

So you can do log base 2 to find the number of guesses

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a little more breakdown from @Wael's answer.

More discussion on the binary search algorithm can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/6-tries-to-guess-a-number-between-1-100) and in [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/3078) we know that **2<sup>N+1</sup>-1** gives us the range (`1..X`) for any number of guesses *N*.

So we can further break this down by saying:

2<sup>N+1</sup>-1 = 800

2<sup>N+1</sup> = 801

log<sub>2</sub>801 = N+1

log<sub>2</sub>801 -1 = N

i.e. 8.646 = N, N = 9

So it will take a maximum of 9 guesses to guess a number between 1 and 800.

I should also point out that **2<sup>N+1</sup>-1** is the *worst case*, and so when trying to find the number of guesses for a given input, it will vary depending on the input.